# How to create Regex to return everything past the last hyphen?

Tags: regex, string

I'm trying to create the regex (something I always struggle with) to return everything past the last hyphen.

For example these would be input strings:
https://mywebsite.com/company/company-name-page-ddd.l
https://mywebsite.com/company/another-company-page-lloy.l

and I'd like to return only the ddd.l or in the 2nd example the lloy.l

I thought it would be something along the lines of ^-([a-zA-Z0-9-.=^$]+)/?$ but this doesn't solve the first part of the URL and directory.

This has to be pure regex, so no php as its being used as a filter in a wordpress plugin on the user side.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could it just be `[^-]+$`?

Comment: @JvdV No, as a general solution that won't work, because it would return everything before the _first_ hyphen, not the last one.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, how so? Maybe I'm just reading this question wrongly, but [this](https://regex101.com/r/ck4o2n/4) is what it would return which matches what OP seems to be after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could turn around the anchors and end with `$` instead of start with `^`

Then you have to remove the `-` from the character class. The value is in group 1.

```
-([a-zA-Z0-9.=^$]+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0n6T4m/1)

If supported, you could also match the hyphen and make use of `\K` or use a positive lookbehind to assert a hyphen on the left `(?<=-)` and omit the group to get *the match only*

`-\K[a-zA-Z0-9.=^$]+$` or `(?<=-)[a-zA-Z0-9.=^$]+$`

As previously php was tagged:

```
$strings = [
    "https://mywebsite.com/company/company-name-page-ddd.l",
    "https://mywebsite.com/company/another-company-page-lloy.l"
];

foreach ($strings as $s) {
    preg_match("~-\K[a-zA-Z0-9.=^$]+$~", $s, $match);
    echo $match[0] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
ddd.l
lloy.l
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `preg_replace` here to strip off all content from the start of the input up to, and including, the final dash:

```
$input = "Some text here - and other text as well - the end";
$output = preg_replace("/^.*-/", "", $input);
echo $input . "\n" . $output;
```

This prints:

```
Some text here - and other text as well - the end
 the end
```

Comment: sorry I've had to revise the question as this cannot be done in php - just regex

Comment: Then use `^.*-(.*)$`, and what you want would be in the first capture group.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is, that you started the expression with `^-` therfore it didn't match.

If I read your problem description, I think you want the whole line to be a full match, but only the part after the last hyphen in the matching group. To do this, I recomend start with `^.*` to catch everything at the start.

so the full regex would be:

```
^.*-([\w.]+)$
```

I really recommend unsing https://regex101.com/ to develop regex.

```
php > preg_match('/^.*-([\w.]+)$/', "https://mywebsite.com/company/company-name- 
page-ddd.l" , $matches);
php > print_r($matches);
Array
(
    [0] => https://mywebsite.com/company/company-name-page-ddd.l
    [1] => ddd.l
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`^.*(-.*)$`

Explanation: assert the start of the line, then select any character 0 or more times, followed by (and start capturing) a hyphen, followed by any character 0 or more times (and close capturing), and assert the end of the line.

The first capture group will have what you need.